# Existential instantiation and singleton set with known element

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

I have been taught that when you apply existential instantiation you cannot instantiate the variable to a particular one or the same one, e.g. from $\exists xFx$ to $Fx$, or from $\exists xFx$ to $Fa$ (where a stands for Arthur, say), it must be to a new variable, e.g. from $\exists x Fx$ to $Fy$.

But what about in the context of a singleton set where the only element is known? For example, let A and B be sets: $\forall x \exists A(A\in\{B\}\land x\in A)  $

If $A\in\{B\}$, then when I instantiate, it is difficult to understand why can I not instantiate $ \exists A(A\in\{B\}\land x\in A)  $ to $B\in\{B\}\land x\in B$, since it is made clear that B is the only set within that set.

Or do I nevertheless have to instantiate it to, say, $C\in\{B\}\land x\in C$, but then say since C and B can be the same and B is the only set within that set, therefore C=B?

Any assistance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The restriction on existential instantiation is needed in order to avoid fallacious derivations like this one:

1) $\exists x P(x)$

2) $\exists x Q(x)$

3) $P(a)$ --- exisential instantiation

4) $Q(a)$ --- exisential instantiaion: **wrong!**

5) $P(a) \land Q(a)$ --- by $\land$-introduction

> 6) $\exists x(P(x) \land Q(x))$ --- by existential generalization.

---

In your specific example, the fallacy is avoided because the "formal" application of the rule with the restriction will lead us to:

> $C ∈ \{ B \} \land x ∈ C$.

But we know that: $C ∈ \{ B \} \leftrightarrow C=B$; thus applying tautological transformations, we may "safely" derive:

> $B ∈ \{ B \} \land x ∈ B$.

Thus, in your example, we can by-pass the unavoidable restriction because we can cosider the "unrestricted" application as a shortcut that works, in *this specific* example.

It is enough to modify slightly your example to:

> $∀x∃A(A ∈ \{ \emptyset, B \} \land x ∈ A)$.

If we instantiate the existetial quantifier with $\emptyset$, what we get is: $(\emptyset ∈ \{ \emptyset, B \} \land x ∈ \emptyset)$, and thus, by sound logical transformations:

> > $∀x(x ∈ \emptyset)$.

Comment: So if instead of instantiating it to C∈{B}∧x∈C first and then infer B∈{B}∧x∈B, instantiating it straight to B∈{B}∧x∈B it would be fallacious? I understand why it is fallacious in your first example but if we know B is the only element it doesn't seem this fallacy could apply?

Comment: Thank you so much! My main question has been fully revolved. But for your modification, how come you can existential instantiate A to ∅? That seems to be the same as instantiating to a particular thing (since there is only one empty set). And ∀x(x∈∅) also doesn't seem to mean anything? (Because an empty set has no element)

Also, may I ask if 'tautological transformation' is an actual inference rule, or did you just mean that since we derived C=B, we can replace all C with B? Because I cannot Google it as an inference rule anywhere.

Comment: @DanielMak - the example with $\emptyset$ is thinked exactly to show what happens when we instantiate $∃xFx$ to $Fa$, when the individual *constant* $a$ is not "new".

Comment: @DanielMak - about "tautological transformations" I mean using logical (propositional) rules: from $C ∈ \{ B \} \land x \in C$ apply [Conjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination) to "unpack" $C ∈ \{ B \}$, replace $C$ with $B$ by the  equivalence and the [Equality rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) of substitution to get: $B ∈ \{ B \}$ and the same for $x \in B$ and finally apply [Conjunction introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_introduction) to re-assemble: $B ∈ \{ B \} \land x \in B$.

Comment: thank you so much for your patient and detailed explanation!